# Find function $f$ such that $f(x)\ln[f(x)]=x$

Tags: analysis

Find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)
\ln [f(x)]=x$ for $x\in D$ open.

Comment: The function $f(x) = 3$ works for $D = \varnothing$, which is open. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: How about $\exp W(x)$ in terms of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: No closed form for such function :(